# Undefined values with new Array() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

Looking at some javascript code, I saw (something like) this:

```
var arr = Array.apply(null, {length: 10});
```

Reading the MDN documentation for Function.prototype.apply(), I learnt that although it usually expects an array as its second argument which is an array of the arguments to be passed to the invoked function,

> you can also use any kind of object which is array-like, so in practice this means it's going to have a property length and integer properties in the range (0...length).

So from what I could tell, it's calling Array() as if it was passed 10 arguments, but since it doesn't define any of those "integer properties", it's as if it was passed 10 undefined arguments. **Is that correct?**

```
console.log(arr);
```

yields

> [ undefined,
>     undefined,
>     undefined,
>     undefined,
>     undefined,
>     undefined,
>     undefined,
>     undefined,
>     undefined,
>     undefined ]

Which is totally different to the result of

```
var barr = new Array(10);
console.log(barr);
```

which is

> [ , , , , , , , , ,  ]

These arrays also behave differently.

```
console.log(arr.map(function(item) { return 'hi';}));
console.log(barr.map(function(item) { return 'hi';}));
```

gives

> [ 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi' ]
>
> [ , , , , , , , , ,  ]

I wanted to know why the map function didn't work for the second one. So I checked `console.log(1 in arr);` which gave *true* and `console.log(1 in barr);' which gave *false*.

So my current guess is that arr is an array which contains as integer properties 10 variables which each have the value of *undefined* and barr is an array which, although it has a length of 10, has no integer properties. And Array.apply works because it asks {length: 10} what its property *0* is, receives *undefined*, and so assigns *undefined* to the property *0* of the array it's constructing, and so on. Is my reasoning correct? And is there really no less hackish way to define an array which contains undefined integer properties for each index within its range, rather than having no integer properties at all? Because looking at this, it seems to me that `new Array()` is pretty useless.

Comment: And yes, the `Array` constructor is rarely useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So from what I could tell, it's calling Array() as if it was passed 10 arguments, but since it doesn't define any of those "integer properties", it's as if it was passed 10 undefined arguments. Is that correct?

Yes, exactly. It's doing this:

```
var arr = Array(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined);
```

> ```
> var barr = new Array(10);
> console.log(barr);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> console.log(arr.map(function(item) { return 'hi';}));
> console.log(barr.map(function(item) { return 'hi';}));
> ```
>
> I wanted to know why the map function didn't work for the second one.

Because `map`, `forEach`, and similar only visit properties that actually exist. As you said, there's a big difference between.

```
var arr = Array(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined);
// Or `var arr = Array.apply(null, {length: 10});
```

and

```
var barr = new Array(10);
```

In the first example, `arr` has 10 entries, each of which has the value `undefined`. In the second example, `barr` has **no entries** and a `length` of `10`. So in the first one, `map` will visit the properties, because they exist. In the second one, it won't, because they don't.

Recall that standard arrays in JavaScript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) *(disclosure: that's a post on my blog)*, they're objects with some special behavior. As such, they're inherently *sparse*:

```
var a = [];
a.length = 10000;
```

`a` doesn't have 10,000 entries. It has *no* entries. It's just that its `length` property is `10000`.

You can tell whether the property exists by using `hasOwnProperty` or `in`. Compare:

```
var barr = new Array(10);
console.log(barr.hasOwnProperty(0)); // false
console.log(0 in barr);              // false
```

to:

```
var arr = Array.apply(null, {length: 10});
console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty(0));  // true
console.log(0 in arr);               // true
```

> And `Array.apply` works because it asks `{length: 10}` what its property `0` is, receives `undefined`, and so assigns `undefined` to the property `0` of the array it's constructing, and so on. Is my reasoning correct?

Yes, although to be clear, it's `apply` that's asking what property `0` is, and then it's using that as the first argument when calling `Array`. It's `Array` that then takes the first argument's value and assigns it to the `0` property on the array it's creating.

> And is there really no less hackish way to define an array which contains undefined integer properties for each index within its range, rather than having no integer properties at all?

Only slightly: ES2015 adds `Array.from`, which accepts an array-like object and returns a true array (optionally mapping the entries). So that would be:

```
var arr = Array.from({length:10});
```

It's rare to need to do that, as opposed to simply `a = new Array(bigNumberHere);` or `a = []; a.length = bigNumberHere`. E.g., many times you don't care if the property doesn't exist or exists with the value `undefined`. Sometimes you do, but to give you perspective, I've been writing JavaScript professionally for 20 years, fairly intensively the last 8, and I've probably cared, oh, once or twice, tops.

You mentioned that in the specific case you were dealing with, it was combined with `map`, so `Array.from` would take the place of both:

```
var arr = Array.from({length: 10}, function() { return "hi"; });
```

...yields

```
["hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi"]
```

Although `Array.from` is new in ES2015, it can be shimmed/polyfilled on older JavaScript engines.

Comment: In this particular instance it was because the coder went on to use map on the same line, `return Array.apply(null, {length: 100}).map(function(value, index) { ... });`, trying to write as concisely as possible as an exercise. Not necessary, I agree, but it turned out to be very educational. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PoolOfPeas: Makes sense. I should have mentioned `Array.from` in the above (and now I have). :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is that correct?

Yes

> you can also use any kind of object which is array-like, so in
>   practice this means it's going to have a property length and integer
>   properties in the range (0...length).

It says that you can pass a **duck-type** of an array: an object that has a sort of interface:

1. a length property (for iteration)
2. optional: some integer properties (the values)

This will be treated as an Array.
So passing a { length: 10 } is like pass a real array [undefined,undefined,undefined,..]
where each index is created and has value undefined.

So the first code row:

```
var arr = Array.apply(null, {length: 10});
```

is interpreted as:

```
var arr = Array(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined)
```

> So my current guess is that arr is an array which contains as integer
>   properties 10 variables which each have the value of undefined and
>   barr is an array which, although it has a length of 10, has no integer
>   properties.

Yes.

`var test = Array(10);`

it outputs: [undefined x10] <-- no indexes, only a simple property 'length' unaligned with the real content, but useful for retrieve it and do some size condiderations.

`test[2] = undefined;`

it outputs: [undefined x2, undefined, undefined x7] <-- no indexes except for the position '2' that has a value: undefined.