# Allocate new array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to allocate new array with values.

Case 1 :

```
var x = new Array(3).map(()=>1);
```

Now `x` is `[undefined * 3]`

Case2 :

```
var x = [...new Array(3)].map(()=>1);
```

And now `x` is `[1,1,1]`

Can someone help here?

Why using this **spread operator** makes such a difference?

And why Case 1 **doesn't work** ?

Comment: FYI, it's called *spread element*, because the `...` are not an operator.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator   @FelixKling

Comment: Yes, MDN is wrong. It's also conflating all the different `...` use cases.

Comment: Could you write down where to find the right documents, so let others know. @FelixKling

Comment: `Array(3).fill(1)`

Comment: @WeiWang: I haven't found a great source yet, except for the spec (which is not necessarily straightforward to understand). I'd love to update the MDN article, but I'm not that familiar with the editing tools (e.g. how the articles are categorized). Maybe I should just write a blog post myself. Why I think it's important that people don't mistake the `...` as an operator: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35019557/218196 .

Comment: @FelixKling If you have a blog to write on about that. It'd be awesome.

Comment: @choz: In theory I have a blog... with 10 blog posts the last one from 5 years ago or so :D

Answer (score 14):

**tl;dr:** The first array has holes, the second one doesn't. `.map` skips holes.

---

By using a spread element, the array is treated as an *iterable*, i.e. you get an iterator to iterate over the array. The iterator basically works like a `for` loop, it will iterate the array from index `0` to index `array.length - 1` (see [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-createarrayiterator) for details), and add the value at each index to the new array. Since your array doesn't contain any values, `array[i]` will return `undefined` for every index.

That means, `[...new Array(3)]` results in an array that literally contains three `undefined` values, as opposed to just a "spare" array of length `3`.

See the difference in Chrome:

[image]

We call "sparse arrays" also "arrays with **holes**".

**Here is the crux**: Many array methods, including `.map`, **skip** holes! They are not treating the hole as the value `undefined`, the completely ignore it.

You can easily verify that by putting a `console.log` in the `.map` callback:

```js
Array(3).map(() => console.log('call me'));
// no output
```

And that's the reason your first example doesn't work. You have a sparse array with only holes, which `.map` ignores. Creating a new array with the spread element creates an array without holes, hence `.map` works.

Comment: This Answer could be canonical as relating to `spread element`. Or perhaps  a new canonical as to the `spread element`? Have not read that term previously

Comment: Note, not that good, here, at asking Questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper . Please advise if Question should be updated to include more details

Answer (score 3):

[`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

> **arrayLength**
>
> If the only argument passed to the `Array` constructor is an integer between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (inclusive), this returns a new
>   JavaScript array with length set to that number.

`new Array(3)` does not actually create iterable values at created array having `.length` property set to `3`.

See also [Undefined values with new Array() in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100285/undefined-values-with-new-array-in-javascript) .

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) at first example to return expected results

```
var x = Array.from(Array(3)).map(()=>1);
```

[Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

> The spread operator allows an expression to be expanded in places
>   where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements
>   (for array literals) or multiple variables  (for destructuring
>   assignment) are expected.

```
var x = [...new Array(10)].map(()=>1);
```

creates an array having values `undefined` and `.length` set to `10` from `Array(10)`, which is iterable at `.map()`

Comment: Could you explain what is going on here.

Comment: Or shorter: `Array.from(Array(3), ()=>1);`

Comment: You didn't explain why the first case didn't work as the OP expected even though the length was set to 3.

Comment: @guest271314: Regarding the comment you deleted: I'm conflicted. On one side I understand that it makes sense to simplify what `...` does exactly, on the other hand, it may give people [a wrong impression](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35019557/218196).

Answer (score 0):

> Why case 1 doesn't work ?

[**Map function calls callback function in each element in ascending order**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19)

In your first case (breaking down..),

```
var x = new Array(3);
x = x.map( () => 1 );
```

`x` is an array with uninitialized index. Therefore, `map` function does not know where to start iterating your array from. And causing it to not *iterating* it at all (Which is not working).

You can test it by (in Chrome),

```
var x = new Array(5);
// This will display '[undefined x 5]' in chrome, because their indexes are uninitialized

x[1] = undefined;
// '[undefined x 1, undefined, undefined x 3]' Only array[1] that has its index.
// And you can use 'map' function to change its value.

x = x.map( () => 1 );
// '[undefined x 1, 1, undefined x 3]'
```

> Why using this spread operator makes such a difference?

In your second sample,

[**Spread operator allows parts of an array literal to be initialized from an iterable expression**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn919259(v=vs.94).aspx)

[And enclose it in square bracket to properly use it.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-initializer)

So, `[...new Array(2)]` is actually an indexed array of `[undefined, undefined]`.

Since your array in the following sample has been indexed. Let's have a look (in Chrome),

```
var x = [...new Array(2)];
// Now 'x' is an array with indexes [undefined, undefined]

x = x.map( () => 1 );
// Will return [1, 1]
```

Now, each value in `x` has its own indexes. Then finally, `map` function is able to iterate over it and call the callback function for each element in ascending order.

Comment: *"Therefore, map does not know where to start iterating your array from."* Well, it could start at `0` ;)

Comment: @FelixKling It'd say 'Which one is `0`'? :)

Comment: Well, `array[Symbol.iterator]()` also manages to iterate over the array without problems (it will simply return `undefined` for holes). I'm sure there are valid reasons why `.map` skip holes, but it's definitely not a technical limitation.

Comment: @FelixKling I believe that array in js has their own indexing methods which makes them iterable. E.g. `var x = []; x[5] = 1;` will make your so called `holes` from its index `0 to 4`. It's quite interesting why MDN doesn't provide this information.